# Can you use android Room library to host a database online

Tags: android, database, android-room

Please I am working on a project for a "travel ticket booking android app". I've already learned how to develop android apps but the problem is that my project will need have an updatable online database from which travelling agencies could be added and users also use it to inspect and choose the different travelling options.

My question is: Can you use android Room library to store information in on an external online server instead of the phone local storage?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's remember Room is abstraction layer over SQL Lite. Thus in theory you should be able to backup your database into file, publish it somewhere online, download it from other places and restore it somewhere else - but that's very very limiting in case you deal with more then one user.

So practical answer to your question is no, you cannot use Room to store info externally online.

As long as you are in Google ecosystem already, you should probably consider Firebase options they are offering: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore. As long as you are using Room, you'll probably have to build some adapter for your data.

Comment: Ah OK and thank you. But may you please give me more hosting options so that I may evaluate their pricing?

Comment: Ideally (for your goals) some relational cloud dabase is needed (so that you could use local Room as cache and sync with remote storage in a natural way). I do not know any free options for that (was searching for my purposes as well). I ended up using Firebase Cloud Firestore but honestly it is quite inconvenient though free for my needs.

Comment: I will go with firebase. In accordance to my project, may you propose any architecture which I can use to structure my project? (It is my first large scale project so I don't really know how to structure it to be reliable)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to go with MVVM (using JetPack) + Repository structure like outlined here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide. You will have all that you may need: 1. lifecycle safe data observing, separation of concerns, you could even use their paging if needed. Plus Room supports livedata out of the box. If choice, I'd recommend Kotlin as language as well (java is fine if no choice).

Comment: Understood. I've been using kotlin and I am familiar with MVVM .Finally, my app will need to have access to a map API. So my question is: Apart from google maps(which you must enable billing), is there any other reliable and robust map service?(For test purposes only)

Comment: Was only using Google (because android). Actually, yes you will have to enable billing but that does not mean it will charge you immediately - I think they have free cap (of course one will have to keep an eye on usage).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218805/discussion-between-ladoken-and-ror).